# What is the directory the header file is included from?

Tags: c

I have a C project with multiple include directories that hold header files with same names but different content. So how can I know which one is included to my main program.

```
IDE - Eclipse
Compiler - IAR for MSP430
Build - Makefiles
```

Comment: Are you using a makefile? Are you using gcc? Are you using autools? Are you under Eclipse IDE? Describe better your "environment".....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your includes use the `<[file.h]>` form, it depends on the include search path of your preprocessor. For `gcc`, any `-I` option will append a path to the include search path. The first matching file is used, so the order of `-I` options matters.

Comment: This answer my question. Thank you.